# Convert multiline textbox items to an array and then search for those items in another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a file containing lines of text which I've read into an array (search). I have a multiline text box the contents of which gets put into an array (lines) with a button click, what I'm trying to do is search the first array with each item from the 2nd array and add the found line to a listView.

I'm getting null for item in the foreach loop. I've tried swapping the foreach statement around with the lines and search arrays with no change.

More info, say the items.lst contains the following.

```
Cats have four legs
Dogs have four legs
Horses have four legs
Elephants have four legs
```

In the multi line text box the user types Dogs and the next line Horses, what I want displayed in the list view when they press the button is:

```
Dogs have four legs
Horses have four legs

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtIndex.Text = @"c:\temp\items.lst";
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string index = @"items.lst";
        string[] search = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(index);
        string[] sep = {"\r\n"};
        string[] lines = txtList.Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string item in lines.Where(item => search.Contains(item)))
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(item + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

6/6/2016
I ended up with the following which worked.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string index = @"items.lst";
    string[] search = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(index);
    string[] sep = { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" };
    string[] lines = txtList.Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string line in search)
    {
        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(item))
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(line + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

And LINQ version

```
foreach (string line in from line in search from item in lines where line.Contains(item) select line)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(line + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: What means that you're "getting null for item in the foreach loop"? `null` or a `NullReferenceException`? `String.Split` does never return `null`, that's why i ask.

Comment: FYI, use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines`, it will return you an `IEnumerable` instead of you splitting everything yourself.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter debugging the foreach line I get item | null when I hover the cursor over the variable, it should be something from the multiline text box.

Answer (score 0):

First modify separator array as

```
string[] sep = { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" };
```

Just add Trim() function (Less mandatory)

```
foreach (string item in lines.Where(item => search.Contains(item.Trim())))
{
            listView1.Items.Add(item + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code use this

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string index = @"items.lst";
        string[] search = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(index);
        string[] sep = {"\r\n"};        
        foreach (string item in search)
        {
            var myitem = lines.Cast<string>().Where(i => item.Contains(i)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (myitem != null && myitem.Trim().Length > 0)
                listView1.Items.Add(myitem + Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.